# Error on Firefox 116 java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, firefox

When executing remotely on Jenkins or browserstack started to get error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class 
com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast 
to class org.openqa.selenium.WebElement 
(com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap and 
org.openqa.selenium.WebElement are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

line that causing issue is

```java
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofMillis(TIME_OUT)).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(LOCATOR));
```

Please help, how can i solve it?

Trying to run our suite, but it is failing only on Firefox, working fine on Edge and Chrome.